# Not able to get list of schema names when I pass publication ID and with ItemTypeCriteria schema by using Broker API

Tags: broker

```
int iPubId = Integer.parseInt(publicationId);
CriteriaFactory criteriaFactory = new CriteriaFactory();
PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(iPubId);
ItemTypeCriteria IsSchema = new ItemTypeCriteria(ItemTypes.SCHEMA);
Criteria allCriteria = criteriaFactory.And(pubCriteria,IsSchema);
Query myQuery = new Query();
myQuery.setCriteria(allCriteria);
SortParameter sortParameter = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ITEMS_TITLE, 
                                                SortParameter.ASCENDING);
myQuery.addSorting(sortParameter);
String[] itemResults = myQuery.executeQuery();
System.out.println("RERERERESULTS:"+itemResults.length);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome the Tridion Stack Exchange. Are you setup to actually publish *schemas*? You can filter to get certain component presentations based on a given schema, but the schemas aren't available in Content Delivery afaik, unless you put them there.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing your issue is related to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530742/schematitlecriteria-yield-no-results-in-sdl-tridion-broker-query

I found that the titles of the schema's names are not actually deployed to the broker until at least one DCP based on that Schema has been published.

Comment: Hmm, I don't read the question this way. It looks like the OP is trying to create a query to get back the list of schema names. The other scenario is about getting DCPs based on a specific schema. Is the full list of schema names possible with the CD API in a single query?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:-

```
Query myQuery = new Query();

Criteria myCriteria = null;
ItemTypeCriteria isSchema = new ItemTypeCriteria(8);
PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(251);
AndCriteria andCriteria = new AndCriteria(isSchema, pubCriteria);

myCriteria = andCriteria;

myQuery.setCriteria(myCriteria);

SortParameter sortParameter = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ITEMS_SCHEMA_ID, 
                                                SortParameter.ASCENDING);

myQuery.addSorting(sortParameter);
//myQuery.setResultFilter(new LimitFilter(25));

String[] itemResults = myQuery.executeQuery();
System.out.println("RESULTS: " + itemResults.length);
```

*Note that I haven't tested yet*

Answer (score 0):

You can, by default, **publish pages and (dynamic) component presentations** to content delivery along with their metadata (including template metadata now, I believe).

*Schemas* may be in the Broker database, but doing the following doesn't make sense (I'd expect components or pages):

```
ItemTypeCriteria IsSchema = new ItemTypeCriteria(ItemTypes.SCHEMA);
```

You can, however, get all CPs based on a specific schema:

```
SchemaTitleCriteria criteria = new SchemaTitleCriteria("article");
```

You could get the list of schemas in delivery by publishing out a configuration (xml) page or store it in a dcp. This *might* be a use case to use the Core Service in delivery, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You could also configure `Tridion.ContentManager.config` to actually render schemas but you'd need a custom resolver along with whatever content delivery code you need to get this information. But it'd be easier to use a template building block assembly.

Comment: Schema Names are  published along with DCPs, but not if the components are just embedded on a page

Comment: Makes sense. In my setup I can see at least two schemas in the schemas table but can't get them back via the API (without first getting the DCPs).

Comment: But I still doubt we can get the *list* of schemas in a single query. :-)